# Django model - set up a "has_many_through" relationship

Tags: django, django-models

Looking for advice on setting up this model.

This job board app has Company, Location, and Job.  They should have the following relationships:

- A Company can have multiple locations
- A Company can have multiple jobs
- A Job can have only one Company
- A Job can have multiple locations, BUT each Location must be valid for the job's Company

I'd like to create a model that reflects these relationships.  I think something like this might work:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()

class Location(models.Model):
    is_primary_location = models.BooleanField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)

class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
```

But I would really like the "Job has Location(s) through Company" relationship to be enforced.  The model doesn't enforce it; I think I'd have to filter the valid Locations when data is displayed, and I'd like to avoid that.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ForeignKey.limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to).

This allows you to filter the available choices and is enforced in ModelForm. Since you already have the company foreign key in your Job model, you should be able to use that to filter the choices.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects and wrote the model like this.  I don't think limit_choices_to works in this case (according to other SO threads)

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey 

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()

class Location(models.Model):
    is_primary_location = models.BooleanField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)

class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    location = ChainedForeignKey(
        Location,
        chained_field="company",
        chained_model_field="company",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True
    )
```

Comment: I ended up not using smart-selects and instead just added a validation rule when jobs are saved:  `if (self.company_id != Location.objects.get(pk=self.location_id).company_id):
            raise ValidationError('Location is not valid for company')`